# Como retirar formatação do comando GETDATE()

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que será usada por vários clientes simultaneamente, gostaria de utilizar como `id` o **Dia, Mes, Ano, Hora, Minuto, Segundo e Milissegundo**, teria como eu retirar as `/` e `:` que a função `GETDATE()` retorna?

Answer (score 6):

Para o SQL Server a partir do 2012, use o [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff' );
```

Veja os [padrões de caracteres de formato de data aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Se for `SQL-SERVER 2008` ou anterior, a função `FORMAT`, muito bem aplicada pelo amigo @gmsantos **não irá funcionar**; Você pode fazer essa função para remover caracteres especiais:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'

    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')

    RETURN @String

END
```

Logo depois é só executar a query com a função, lembrando só de converter o resultado do `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), '^a-z0-9')
```

O resultado será: `20150528095612`

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012802/2386142)

Comment: Bem observado ;)